# SQLite: UPDATE statement with COUNT subquery

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
UPDATE OPERATING_SYSTEM
SET App_Count = 
    (SELECT COUNT(OPERATE.App_ID) AS App_Count 
     FROM OPERATING_SYSTEM , OPERATE WHERE OPERATING_SYSTEM.Name = OPERATE.Operating_System_Name
     GROUP BY OPERATING_SYSTEM.Name);
```

This sub-select returns one count total for every record
[image]

But when you run the query alone, it returns the right count for each record.

[image]

Comment: If you can update your query via desired input/output samples

Answer (score 1):

The way UPDATE statements work is that the sub query gets evaluated for every row in the target table. Since your sub query has no correlation to the update, it will be processed once, and the result will be placed in every row. 
What you are missing is the correlation. For every row being updated, you want to calculate the count for that particular name. Try something like:

```
UPDATE OPERATING_SYSTEM
SET App_Count = 
         (
          SELECT COUNT(O.App_ID) 
          FROM OPERATING_SYSTEM AS OS, OPERATE AS O 
          WHERE OS.Name = O.Operating_System_Name 
                AND OS.Name = OPERATING_SYSTEM.Name
         );
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need:

```
UPDATE OPERATING_SYSTEM 
SET App_Count = (
  SELECT COUNT(App_ID) FROM OPERATE WHERE Operating_System_Name = OPERATING_SYSTEM.Name
)
```

You don't need to join the subquery to the table `OPERATING_SYSTEM`. 
The count you need is there in the table `OPERATE`

Comment: Yes!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

The subquery should not contain a join to OPERATING_SYSTEM:

```
UPDATE OPERATING_SYSTEM
SET App_Count =
    (SELECT COUNT(OPERATE.App_ID) AS App_Count
     FROM OPERATE
     WHERE OPERATING_SYSTEM.Name = OPERATE.Operating_System_Name
     GROUP BY OPERATE.Operating_System_Name);
```

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=80b7394804934ca8b4f88e6ca97445e5)

Answer (score 0):

Your `UPDATE` statement needs a `WHERE` clause. You are updating all the rows to one of the values returned by the subquery (in this case, 18).

Comment: Glad I could help!